# How to rename a sprint in YouTrack 2017.2?

Tags: youtrack

In YouTrack 2017.2, when I go to **Agile Boards** and I click the pencil (edit) icon next to the sprint I want to modify, the **Edit Sprint** dialog pops up but it is unpopulated and no matter what values I enter there is no effect when I click **Apply changes**.

I am logged in as an admin with all privileges.

Am I missing something?  Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?

[image]

Comment: Are there options for editing the name when you clikc the gear/hex? I think from there, there's options to rename a sprint, but i'm not running the latest version.

Comment: @StealthRabbi I looked and looked there but could not find it anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-41387 It's already fixed, the fix is planned to be released within 1-2 weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is released today ( https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-41387), please accept our apologies.

Comment: The fix works great! Thank you for pushing the release cycle to the max -- we understand there might be little hiccups here and there, no problem. :-)